# How can I separate the pins I am receiving from my data into different categories?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I need two separate the pins into groups because when I filter them I need to know which pins belongs to which category.

This is how I recieve them. So there is one group that loads if the int app.value1 is 0 and the other one is if app.value2 is 0.

The reason I need to separate them is because I am doing a filter where I need to separate the two. Should I do two different lists maybe? Or is there a better way?

```
List<Pin> myPins = new List<Pin>();

private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData() 
{
    var pins = new List<Pin> ();

    var getItems = await phpApi.getInfo ();

        foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

            longString = currentItem ["long"].ToString (); 
            latString = currentItem ["lat"].ToString (); 

                if (App.value1 == 0) {  //so this below is the first group of pins then
                        var pin = new Pin ();
                        pin.Position = new Position (latString, longString);
                        pin.Label = "testlabel";
                        pin.Address = "testadress";

                        pins.Add (pin);
                    }

                if (App.value2 == 0) { //second group of pins
                 //i add pins here as well (so the same code as App.value1), but this intvalue is connected to a different "button"
                      pins.Add (pin);
                }

        }
    }
```

And this is my filter that is not working right now because the pin doesnt know which group the belong to:

```
private  async void FilterPins (string filter)
    {
        map.Pins.Clear ();

        foreach(Pin p in myPins) {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter) || (p.Label.Contains(filter)))     {
                map.Pins.Add (p); //this is just a searchfilter via my searchbar that isnt working when I add the code below. If i remove the code below this function works.
            }

            if (App.value1 == 0 ) {
                map.Pins.Add (p);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("add");
            } 


            if (App.value2 == 0 ) {
                map.Pins.Add (p);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("add");
            } 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Pin` class is `sealed`(https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Pin/), it's a bit hard to work around. However you should be able to create two separate `List<Pin>` in which you can place the respective `Pin` objects into based on your filter. You can then swap your respective `Map.Pins` object with which list of `Pin` objects you need to display.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map.Pins/

Otherwise you can create another `POCO` object that contains a `Pin` object and a `string Category` in it.

EX:

`public class PinWithCategory
{
    public Pin Pin {get; set;}
    public string Category {get; set;}
}`

Comment: Yeah i managed to solve it with the help of this. awesome, thx